# Custom Admin Dashboard: Manual Menu Assignment to Modules

Tags: administrator, jdatabase, custom-module

I need to create a **custom Admin dashboard** for my client. He should be able to add, edit custom modules via this dashboard. As far as I know I need to play with `#__modules` table (**jdatabase**).I figured out column `title` consists of module name, `content` consists of the code/content of the module, `position` refers to the position where the module should pop up and so on. The only thing I couldn't figure out is `Menu Assignment`.

How can I manually set the menu's where the module should show up? What database interaction is needed? Which table stores this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you should take a look into the table jos_modules_menu, it is where menu assignments are stored (moduleid and menuid).

Comment: Got what I wanted.